# How do I make a connection to an MS Access database using Codegear C++ builder (2007)

Tags: ms-access, c++builder

This seems to be the hardest thing to get help with - there are no books, no useful google results,  and borland's own help facilities are far to complicated for me to isolate the answers I need.

I want to make a connection to an already existing microsoft access database using builder.

I want to be able add/delete/read the records.  that's all.

Or failing that.  how do I create a simple database/table using builder.  It would be ideal if I had an application that could create a table if it didn't already exist,  then use that table from that point onwards.

I want to avoid creating DSNs.  I want direct access to the database from builder.

If you could point me in the direction of a good online tutorial for this that would be a start.  If you could actually provide the help yourself (ie tell me how to do it, rather than show me an article) that would be great and I'd be very greatful.

Comment: Yeah, https://forums.codegear.com/

Comment: Also add the C++Builder tag to your question, to help people find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in portuguese:

http://www.caloni.com.br/blog/archives/banco-de-dados-no-c-builder

see if fits your question

Comment: Had to use google translator to translate it into English, but once I did it was quite useful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the VCL's ADO components yet?  TADOConnection, TADOCommand, etc.